# Why is my <main></main> stacked on top of my <nav></nav>?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello there i want to ask something related to (maybe) element positioning.

So i've been stuck with this problem for a while. The  and the  are stacking on top of each other. Is there a efficient workaround so the  will be directly under the ? And weirdly the  is stuck there too.

Here's the screenshoot of it:
[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR3P2.png)

Here's my css and html snippet:

```css
@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* FONT */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap');
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
  /*background-color: #FDE500;*/
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.nav-container li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
}


/* NAV */

.zone-nav {
  background-color: #1A1EB0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.nav-container li a {
  color: #FDE500;
}

ul.nav-container {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-container {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
}

.nav-container li a img {
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.item-1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.item-1 {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*.logo {
  margin: auto 0;
}*/

.item-2 {
  margin: auto 0;
  background-color: ;
}

li.item-1.logo img {
  width: 5em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: auto 0;
}

li.item-1.logo {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*    z-index: 1;*/
}


/* MAIN */

.zone-main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: rgb(238, 174, 202);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238, 174, 202, 1) 38%, rgba(148, 187, 233, 1) 100%);
}

.wrap-main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


/* FOOTER */

.zone-footer {
  background-color: #FDE500;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1A1EB0;
  font-weight: 1000;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: safe center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.footer-item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.footer-item-buffer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.push {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home | P.Y.G. Headquarters</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-base.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="zone-nav sticky">
    <ul class="nav-container">
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/join.png" alt="ICON I"><br>JOIN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/home.png" alt="ICON II"><br>HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/lineups.png" alt="ICON I"><br>LINEUPS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item-1 logo"><img src="assets/img/pyg.png" alt="ICON I"></li>
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/tickets.png" alt="ICON III"><br>SCHEDULE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/shopping-bag.png" alt="ICON IV"><br>STORE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/link.png" alt="ICON IV"><br>LINKS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="zone-main">
    <div class="wrap-main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="zone-footer">
    <ul class="footer-container">
      <li class="footer-item">P.Y.G. Administrative Service - Since 2012</li>
      <li class="footer-item-buffer"></li>
      <li class="footer-item push">PRIVACY POLICY</li>
      <li class="footer-item push">HELP</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because `position: fixed;` moves an element out of the normal flow and position it fixed to the viewport. you proberly wanted `position: sticky`

Comment: That is how fixed positioning works, same as absolute - it takes an element out of normal layout flow, so that it doesn't influence the position of other elements any more. You need to either specify a padding/margin, to push you actual main content further down - or looks into `position:sticky` instead.

Comment: @tacoshy AAH thank you so much it was `position: fixed` that made the `<nav>` ignore the positioning of other elements. By the way, do i use `position: sticky` in my `.sticky` class (in the css above)? Again thanks a lot!

Comment: yes. position sticky will keep an element in the normal flow. As soon it reaches the defined point in the viewport it will change to `position: fixed` (semantically be treated as such).

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! I always forget that `position: fixed` is tampering with the element's flow and you reminded me to learn more about the flow. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tacoshy Okay i will try to learn and use the `position: sticky` property and thanks for the solution, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `sticky` css class on the `nav` element.
The `sticky` css class makes your `main` content sticking to the top of the page.

And add the following css on the `body`

```
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This puts all containers (nav, main, footer) under each other.

Comment: why add `display: flex; flex-direction: column`? The normal block-level-element behavior does this by default.